# Another SQL Max/Count Qestion

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count, max

Have seen many Max/Count Qs answered but I can't get my head around this one. Say I have two tables, the first people and the second result_sets. They contain data as follows;

people table, an ID and a gender flag (amongst others);

```
p_id    p_gen  
1       1
2       1
3       0
4       1
5       0
5       1
```

result_set table

```
r_id    p_id    a_id    s_id    t_id  
1       1       0       5       0  
2       1       1       5       0  
3       1       2       5       0  
4       1       3       5       0  
18      1       0       6       1  
19      1       1       6       1  
20      1       2       5       1  
21      1       3       6       1  
52      4       0       5       0  
53      4       1       5       0  
54      4       2       5       0  
55      4       3       5       0  
69      4       0       5       1  
70      4       1       6       1  
71      4       2       6       1  
72      4       3       5       1  
103     5       0       5       0  
104     5       1       5       0  
111     5       8       6       0  
112     5       9       6       0  
113     5       10      5       0  
120     5       0       6       1  
121     5       1       6       1  
128     5       8       6       1  
129     5       9       6       1  
130     5       10      6       1  
137     5       0       6       2  
138     5       1       6       2  
145     5       8       7       2  
146     5       9       6       2  
147     5       10      7       2  
205     2       0       5       0  
206     2       1       5       0  
207     2       2       5       0
```

What I'd like to do, in English, is something like this;

With regard to the result_set table, ignore s_id when it is zero. group on a_id col (there are 17 a_id values in total, 0-16) total up how many of each s_id value they have but only counting rows with the highest t_id. So if 2 or more rows have the same a_id & p_id, only count the one with the highest t_id. So, for the above data set, the first 4 rows would be ignored as the 4 below relate to the same p_id & a_id but have a greater t_id. Rows 9-12 would not be counted for the same reasons and rows 17-26 ignored for the same reasons, i.e. rows 27-31 have a higher p_id. The last 3 rows shown would be counted.

So, I'd like to return (from the above data);

```
a_id    s_id    Qty  
0       5       2  
0       6       2  
1       5       1  
1       6       3  
2       5       5  
2       6       1  
3       5       1
3       6       1  
8       7       1  
9       6       1  
10      7       1
```

To complicate matters further, I'd like to filter the data based on the p_gen column of the people table. i.e. data only for p_id where the p_gen is 1, say.

I hope I've got across what I was trying to explain. Obviously I need to study SQL a deal more than I have but having already poured (and googled) over this for a couple of days, I really could do with some help.

I hope it's not something too simple!

Cheers,

My apologies as I'm not really sure how to edit replies so in reply to Daniel B (@daniel-b ?), your query returned s_id values that contain zero which I want to ingnore and omitted other s_id values that should be there. Possibly I didn't do a good job of explaining. Anyway, using my actual data, your query returned;

```
a_id    s_id    Qty  
===================
0       0       14  
0       6       1  
1       0       14  
1       6       1  
2       0       14  
2       5       1  
3       0       14  
3       6       1  
4       0       14  
4       6       1  
5       0       14  
5       6       1  
6       0       14  
6       6       1  
7       0       14  
7       6       1  
8       0       14  
8       7       1
```

etc ...

This is way nearer than I got. All 17 a_id values are present and the total s_id values  for each a_id (14+1) are corerect as there are 15 people but s_id values of zero should not be there and more values of 5 should be. I'll see if I can work out what's missing.

Cheers,

Edit #2, success!

Many many thanks to Daniel B, who provided me with the much needed answer (not much hair left). A very slight tweek to the query provided by Daniel B (probably because of my inabillity to explain properly), i.e. moving the s_id filter (WHERE s_id <> 0) into the subquery has done the trick. It resulted in this;

```
SELECT rs.a_id, rs.s_id, COUNT(rs.s_id) Qty  
FROM result_set rs  
INNER JOIN  
(SELECT p_id, a_id, MAX(t_id) t_id FROM result_set WHERE s_id <> 0 GROUP BY p_id, a_id) X  
ON rs.p_id=X.p_id AND rs.a_id=X.a_id AND rs.t_id = X.t_id  
INNER JOIN people p ON p.p_id = rs.p_id  
WHERE p.p_gen = 1  
GROUP BY rs.a_id, rs.s_id  
Order by a_id
```

I now need to study it to understand fully what's going on. Thanks again Daniel B.

Comment: The DBMS is SQL Server (2008 R2). Thnks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT rs.a_id, rs.s_id, COUNT(rs.s_id) 
FROM result_set rs
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT p_id, a_id, MAX(t_id) t_id FROM result_set GROUP BY p_id, a_id) X
ON rs.p_id=X.p_id AND rs.a_id=X.a_id AND rs.t_id = X.t_id
INNER JOIN people p ON p.p_id = rs.p_id
WHERE p.p_gen = @Gender_Variable
AND NOT rs.s_id = 0
GROUP BY rs.a_id, rs.s_id
```

The inner join to to subselect is to only include the highest t_id per p_id and a_id.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this. The query returns s_id with values of zero, which I want to ignore and is missing other s_id values. Sorry, new to this format so will edit my post.

Comment: Added a filter to remove zero s_id values. Which s_id values are you missing?

Comment: The filter results in only one set of a_id/s_id values, i.e. 16 rows, 1 per a_id, each holding the highest s_id value per a_id.

Comment: I dont't understand what is wrong, with the sample data you present i get the resultset you describe. Please use this sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e4e26/2/0 to demonstrate, perhaps more data is needed (such as the zero s_id values which are not in the sample data).

Comment: Many thanks Daniel, amazing stuff bearing in mind no access to the data. A slight tweek as described in my last edit. Can't vote up though unfortunately, no reputation!